# Is it best to check an object's class before casting?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, casting

Should I just cast a variable, or use `isKindOfClass:` to check it and then cast? Which one will be better and more efficient? (Well, efficiency isn't an issue just for a little bit.) I want `string` below to be an `NSString`.

Example:

```
NSString *string = (NSString *)result;
```

or:

```
if(![string isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]
{
   //cast it
}
```

Comment: Is `result` an `id`? And do you *realistically* expect it can be of ANY type? If so, you'd better check the class rather than just blindly casting it. For starters, you're casting to a pointer type, so casting from base types like `NSInteger` won't work. Not even sure if the runtime handles casting an `NSNumber *` to string properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although just casting would be more efficient it may be better for your app if you first check if the result is what you think it is.

It all depends on how safe you want to be

Answer (score 6):

Casting doesn't have any runtime effect. It's only a message to the compiler that you're sure it's okay to assign from one type to another (it'll also silence warnings about "may not respond to" when you've got an `id`).

```
NSString * s = (NSString *)[NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
// The compiler will let you do this, but it's pointless, because:
[s floatValue];    // Okay; NSNumber also implements -floatValue
[s lowercaseString];    // Crashes; s is still an NSNumber instance, 
                        // which doesn't respond to -lowercaseString
```

On the flip side, `isKindOfClass:` doesn't have any effect at compile time; it's sent, just like any other message, at runtime, and its result is determined then.

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I can't think of anything useful that can done by combining these two mechanisms.

There's no reason to send `isKindOfClass:` before casting, but not for the reasons you think. Either you know the class at compile time, in which case `isKindOfClass:` is pointless, or you don't, in which case casting is ineffectual.

Comment: The `isKindOfClass:` check establishes that the object you hold at runtime really is an NSString (or whatever). The cast, like you said, silences warnings. Combining them is worthwhile when an object comes from user input (e.g., a plist) and you want to verify which class it's an instance of, then treat it as such an instance without piling up warnings.

Comment: I completely disagree that combining the two is useless. Combining the two is the only sensible way to do it. Yes, you don't know the class at compile time, and that is why you check via `isKindOfClass:` whether it is a certain class or not. Only if it is a certain type (inside the if) will you cast it and use it in a convenient and type-checked way. If it is not the desired type, you can throw an error or do nothing. Casts in Java, for example, are *exactly* a combination of 1) runtime check of the class and throwing error if it is not, and 2) casting the compile-time type